# Subtracting three time columns in R

Tags: r, datetime, time

I have a question about subtracting columns of time from R.  I have three columns that I need to subtract from one another to get a total amount of observation time.  I need to do
`(TIMEEND-TIMESTART)-TIMEOUT`.

When I use `OBSTIME <- difftime(pipers$TIMEEND, pipers$TIMESTART, units = "hours")`, I get the first part, but how do I subtract the `TIMEOUT` from this.  Or is there a way of subtraction all three columns at the same time?  Is this even the correct format to be doing this in?

Thank in advance for the help!

Michelle

```
$ TIMESTART : POSIXct, format: "2013-10-28 10:30:00" "2013-10-28 14:50:00" "2013-10-28 14:50:00" ...
 $ TIMEEND   : POSIXct, format: "2013-10-28 12:30:00" "2013-10-28 16:50:00" "2013-10-28 16:50:00" ...
 $ TIMEOUT   : POSIXct, format: "2013-10-28 00:04:00" "2013-10-28 00:10:00" "2013-10-28 00:10:00" ..
```

Comment: Is `TIMEOUT` really a duration?

Comment: Subtracting a date-time value from a difftime makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *assume* that TIMEOUT originally referred to a *period*, a 'break' in the observation bout, which in some way has been converted to `POSIXct`. So now it appears as a date. Well, given that my guess has anything to do with reality you may try something like this. Here I use the functions `hour` and `minute` from package `lubridate` to extract relevant (my guess...) parts of the 'out' object.

```
library(lubridate)

# using your first set of times/periods as example
end <- as.POSIXct("2013-10-28 12:30:00")
start <- as.POSIXct("2013-10-28 10:30:00")
out <- as.POSIXct("2013-10-28 00:04:00")

# calculate total duration as difference between 'end' and 'start', in units minutes
tot <- as.numeric(difftime(end, start, units = "mins")) 

# calculate break in minutes using hour and minute components extracted from 'out'.
out_min <- (hour(out) * 60 + minute(out))

# calculate net duration of observation
tot - out_min
# [1] 116
```

Of course this needs to be adjusted if there are additional time units in 'TIMEOUT', e.g. seconds or days.